# How to install OpenCV 4 on Travis CI?

Tags: opencv, travis-ci

I try to use Travis CI to build and run test for my program that using OpenCV 4.0.

I try this in my `install` `.travis.yml` file section:

```
install:
  - sudo apt-get install -qq g++-7
  - sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-7 90

  # OpenCV dependencies - Details available at: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html
  - sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
  - sudo apt-get install -y cmake git libgtk2.0-dev pkg-config libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev
  - sudo apt-get install -y python-dev python-numpy libtbb2 libtbb-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libtiff-dev libjasper-dev libdc1394-22-dev

  - git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
  - git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib.git
  - cd opencv

  # Create a new 'build' folder.
  - mkdir build
  - cd build

  # Set build instructions for Ubuntu distro.
  - cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_QT=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON ..

  # Run 'make' with four threads.
  - make -j4

  # Install to OS.
  - sudo make install

  # Add configuration to OpenCV to tell it where the library files are located on the file system (/usr/local/lib)
  - sudo sh -c 'echo "/usr/local/lib" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/opencv.conf'

  - sudo ldconfig
  - echo "OpenCV installed."
```

But it gave me timeout error at 68% of `make` : `The job exceeded the maximum time limit for jobs, and has been terminated.`

Is there any better way to install OpenCV on Travis CI ?

Maybe some in-built mechanism?

Or if there is some way to disable this timeout protection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable BUILD_EXAMPLES, BUILD_TESTS and BUILD_PERF_TESTS

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I used this command to build OpenCV on Travis CI without timeout:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_apps=OFF -D BUILD_DOCS=OFF -D BUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -D BUILD_TESTS=OFF -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
```